# MySQL joining table columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am a VERY new person to this and I need some assistance.

```
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT owners_dogs.dog_id, dog.name, FROM owners_dogs 
        LEFT JOIN dog ON owners_dogs.dog_id = dog.id WHERE owners_dogs.person_id=$currId ORDER BY dog.name;";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {    
            echo "<i>Owner of: </i>";
            echo "<div style='padding-left:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>";
            while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                echo "<a href='details.php?id=$line->dog_id'>";
                echo "$line->name </a><? if(dog.certfied == '1') echo "CP" ?><br>";
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>
```

I am missing something... I am trying to get the script to echo some text if dog.certified = 1

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `dog.name, FROM` `,` should not be there !

Comment: No problem that you are new, but please ask a clear question. That includes, for instance, the error message that you got, specific behaviour that you experienced, etcetera. Also, please take note of the fact that `mysql_query` and the other `mysql_*` functions are removed in PHP 7, so instead of learning about these old functions, you'd better focus your efforts on a newer API, like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Also, you will find your output does not work because you've got opening and closing PHP tags inside of a string. Use concatenation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1: remove "," from first line

Point 2: remove ";" from second line after `dog.name`

Point 3: The line `echo "$line->name </a><? if(dog.certfied == '1') echo "CP" ?><br>";`
    should be like `echo "$line->name </a>"; if($line->certfied == '1') echo "CP <br>";`

```
Here is the code with correction
<?php
    $query = "SELECT owners_dogs.dog_id, dog.name, dog.certfied FROM owners_dogs 
    LEFT JOIN dog ON owners_dogs.dog_id = dog.id WHERE owners_dogs.person_id=$currId ORDER BY dog.name";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {    
        echo "<i>Owner of: </i>";
        echo "<div style='padding-left:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>";
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
            echo "<a href='details.php?id=$line->dog_id'>";
            echo "$line->name </a>"; if($line->certfied == '1') echo "CP <br>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two possible errors 
1. To use value of `certfied` for comparison, you should first fetch that data within your query.
2. And you can't directly use `dog.certfied` in the while loop, instead use `$line->certfied`.

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT owners_dogs.dog_id, dog.name, dog.certfied, FROM owners_dogs
    LEFT JOIN dog ON owners_dogs.dog_id = dog.id WHERE owners_dogs.person_id=$currId ORDER BY dog.name;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >0 )
{
    echo "<i>Owner of: </i>";
    echo "<div style='padding-left:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>";
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        $dog_id = $line->dog_id;
        $name = $line->name;


        echo "<a href='details.php?id=".$dog_id."'>";
        echo $name."</a>";
        if($line->certfied == '1');
        {
            echo "CP"."<br>";
        }

    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: You were the first one that got this. U got my upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $query = "SELECT owners_dogs.dog_id, dog.name, certified FROM owners_dogs
        LEFT JOIN dog ON owners_dogs.dog_id = dog.id WHERE owners_dogs.person_id=$currId ORDER BY dog.name;";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) >0 )
    {
        echo "<i>Owner of: </i>";
        echo "<div style='padding-left:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>";
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $dog_id = $line->dog_id;
            $name = $line->name;


            echo "<a href='details.php?id=".$dog_id."'>";
            echo $name."</a>";
            if($line->certfied == '1');
            {
                echo "CP"."<br>";
            }

        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Errors are

1. `<? if(dog.certfied == '1')` No php executes on here
2. `echo "CP" ?><br>";` error in here
3. remove `,` on here `dog.name, FROM`
4. Missing table filed (`certified`) in select Query.

Comment: $line->certified will not work in your code

Comment: @CodeGodie any reason ??

Comment: Because certified needs to be in the SELECT line

Comment: @CodeGodie i didnt  get you

Comment: Look at your query here: SELECT owners_dogs.dog_id, dog.name FROM owners_dogs
. As you can see you are only selecting the dogs I'd and name but no 'certified'

Comment: @CodeGodie thanks man. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

### Query Changes

Add the column `certified` in `SELECT` list

```
$query = "SELECT owners_dogs.dog_id, dog.name, certified FROM owners_dogs 
    LEFT JOIN dog ON owners_dogs.dog_id = dog.id 
    WHERE owners_dogs.person_id = $currId ORDER BY dog.name;";
```

If the column `certified` is only in one table, this query will work. Otherwise please add table alias to the column `certified`

### Code Changes

```
echo '<a href="details.php?id=$line->dog_id">'.$line->name.'</a>';
echo ((strcmp($line->certfied, '1') == 0) ? "CP" : "")."<br>";
```

### Explanation

There are two strings which we echo in `echo ((strcmp($line->certfied, '1') == 0) ? "CP" : "")."<br>";`

1. `((strcmp($line->certfied, '1') == 0) ? "CP" : "")`
2. `"<br>";`

In the first part we use a ternary operator which comprises of three parts

- `condition` ? `true value` : `false value`

it evaluates your given condition, if its true then it returns the `true value` other wise `false value`. Now our condition is `(strcmp($line->certfied, '1') == 0)` i.e. compare `$line->certified` with `1`. If both are equal strcmp returns `0`. So if `$line->certified == 1` `"CP"` will be returned other wise an empty string

In the second part we only have a string `"<br>"`

Both parts are concatenated are resultant string is `echo`ed

Comment: thank you - this is tough for an old man trying to learn all of this :)

Comment: nothing is tougher than your will, keeping learning

Comment: The example is not working - no matter if the certified is 1 or 0 it still displays the "CP"

Comment: Will not work because certified needs to be SELECTed first

Comment: @mhollibush, please see the updated answer. Thanks CodeGodie for pointing this out, I'd totally missed it

Comment: Ok I understand the logic, the column certified is actually in the dog table - so I would need to call that from dog.certified?

Comment: if its in only dog table then both `certified` or `dog`.`certified` will work. If its in both tables, then `certified` will not work but either `dog`.`certified` or `owners_dogs`.`certified` will work

Comment: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM owners_dogs LEFT JOIN dog ON owners_dogs.dog_id = dog.id WHERE owners_d' at line 1

Comment: GOT IT - thank you for your help - This will actually help in multiple areas of the scripts - I appreciate your time

Comment: looks like a spelling mistake. did you try with or without table alias? also there should not be a `,` before `FROM`